# Delete Inner Join in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-delete

I have 3 tables and I made an inner join.

`car_table`

```
|car_id|  car  |    
|------| ------| 
|1     | Passat|
```

`property_model`

```
|model_id|  p_value |
|--------|   -----  | 
|1       |   year   |
|2       |   color  |
|3       |   gear   |
|4       |   fuel   |
|5       |   km     |
```

`property_value`

```
|value_id| car_id  | model_id | rs_value |
|--------| -----   | -----    |  -----   |
|1       |   1     |     1    |2020      |
|2       |   1     |     2    |Black     |
|3       |   1     |     3    |Automatic |
|4       |   1     |     4    |Diesel    |
|5       |   1     |     5    |10.000    |
```

I want to delete values in property_value table. But I couldn't, can you help me?

The code i wrote is here.

```
DELETE property_value
FROM property_value

INNER JOIN cars ON
property_value.car_id=cars.car_id

INNER JOIN property_model ON
property_model.model_id=property_value.model_id

WHERE value_id='1'
```

Comment: `WHERE value_id='1'` should be before `GROUP BY`

Comment: @lucumt now i am getting an error like this, 'value_id' MULTI DELETE

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Views, but in this instance (and carefully constructed), I think they may simplify your ongoing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teasing apart comments, I suspect you're after something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS car_table;

CREATE TABLE car_table
(car_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,car  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO car_table VALUES
(1,'Passat');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS property_model;

CREATE TABLE property_model
(model_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,p_value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO property_model VALUES
(1,'year'),
(2,'color'),
(3,'gear'),
(4,'fuel'),
(5,'km');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS property_value;

CREATE TABLE property_value
(value_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,car_id INT NOT NULL
,model_id INT NOT NULL
,rs_value VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO property_value VALUES
(1,1,1,'2020'),
(2,1,2,'Black'),
(3,1,3,'Automatic'),
(4,1,4,'Diesel'),
(5,1,5,'10000');
```

...

```
DELETE v
  FROM property_model a 
  JOIN property_value v 
    ON v.model_id = a.model_id
  JOIN car_table e
    ON e.car_id = v.car_id
 WHERE e.car_id = 1;
 
SELECT * FROM property_value;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.that's exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to delete value,so there is no need to use `GROUP BY`

```
DELETE
FROM property_value

INNER JOIN cars ON
property_value.car_id=cars.car_id

INNER JOIN property_model ON
property_model.model_id=property_value.model_id
WHERE value_id='1'
```

BTW there are two syntax errors in your original sql:

1. `DELETE FROM table` not delete from column
2. when you using `GROUP BY`,it's need to be after `WHERE`

Comment: Group BY Our goal is to pull rows into a single column and delete them based on a single id value.

Comment: @JustFeel when you want to delete it,there is no need to group them,unnecessary

Comment: If I don't need to group, there will be more than one id value, how can I delete them in bulk?

Comment: @JustFeel just have a try and you will got it

Comment: I tried what you said but it only deletes one column. I want it to delete all lines from 1 to 5